# Javascript concat clearing input fields

Tags: javascript, html, string-concatenation

```js
function js() {
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = document.getElementById("example").innerHTML+"<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" />";
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" />
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="js();">Click</button>
```

I have a form, which need variable number of input types.

```
<form action="" method="">
   [...]
   <div id="mezok">
      <div id="input_id">
         <input type="text" name="name" />
      </div>
   </div>
[...]
</form>
```

I add and remove further inputs (along with their divs!) via an ajax call. Javascript calls a php which generates a new input_id div, and then concatenates to the rest of the div id="mezok". Adding and removing inputs are fine as long as everything is empty. However, when I add a new div when there is something in the input, it clears the rest of the inputs.

```
document.getElementById("mezok").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mezok").innerHTML+http.responseText;

document.getElementById("mezok").innerHTML += http.responseText;

document.getElementById("mezok").innerHTML.concat(http.responseText);
```

(The last one is not working at all...)

TL;DR: concat input to input, values of inputs disappear. :'(

Comment: String.prototype.concat returns a new string, it doesn't change the string that needs to be concatenated. I suggest you take the time to create an example of your problem that can be run here on stackoverflow. Edit your message and click on the 7th button starting from the left on top of the body of the text editor.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That so cool, I thought it was some foreign site coder thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below could be a solution for you. In this way you're not going to overwrite the existing inputs with the associated values while you're adding new inputs.

```js
function js() {
    var inputElementToAppend = document.createElement('input');
    inputElementToAppend.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" />";
    document.getElementById("example").appendChild(inputElementToAppend.firstChild);
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" />
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="js();">Click</button>
```

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: document.createElement('input'); Do you have a list for the acceptable arguments for this one? (I swear JS documentations are written by psychopaths...).

Comment: @kry I don't know where you look for the documentation, but Mozilla is pretty clear with all that info: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: The only thing I learned from this page it accepts 'div' and null. However, when I use null, my div is surrounded by a '<null>' tag.

Comment: I'm not getting any element appended, it now looks like this: `var inputElementToAppend = document.createElement('div');
                    inputElementToAppend.innerHTML = http.responseText; document.getElementById("mezok").appendChild(inputElementToAppend.firstChild);` If I log into the console, it's fine, but nothing is being appended, and there are no error messages.

Comment: @kry Because `createElement` is to create elements. You specify the tag (img, div, input, span, etc...) as the first parameter and some options as the second. I think is pretty clear xD With that element created, then you can work with it individually. Check my answer. I think that you need to follow a basic Javascript/HTML tutorial before diving into this.

Comment: @kry I recommend you to recheck the code as this code is a bit garbage. Is creating an input element and then inserting another input element inside the input element created, then extracts it, adds it to the container and discards the first parent input element created. The first parent input created can be a div, img or whatever element, as is just a container to create another element via `innerHTML`. Really bad performant.

Comment: Yeah, I already reformatted it, since I'm using huge divs and not inputs. I ( and he) was just using as an example. Now the deleting is not working, since it surrounds the whole code with a <div> tag, which is added at `var inputElementToAppend = document.createElement('input');` I will try to think up something.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `innerHTML`. What you are doing is redrawing the entire container contents, deleting existent inputs and creating new inputs each time. My experience says that when you are accessing `innerHTML`, recheck your code as you are probably doing something weird.

What you have to do is to create inputs individually and append them to the container, without touching the rest of the inputs. Is like appending elements to an array.

This way the code is more self-explanatory, and better, is way more performant:

```js
function js() {
    var input = document.createElement("input"); // Create a new input element. Is like "<input>".
    input.setAttribute("type", "text"); // Set the 'type' attribute to 'text'. Is like having '<input type="text">'
    input.setAttribute("name", "name[]"); // Set the 'name' attribute to 'name[]'. Is like having '<input name="name[]">' but because you already have set the type, now is like having '<input type="text" name="name[]">'
    document.getElementById("example").appendChild(input); // Push it to the container
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" />
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="js();">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Following working fine for me.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo">ABC</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += `<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" />`;
}
<script>
```

I would recommend to use `appendChild` and `removeChild` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: That will overwrite the actual value of all inputs each time. Try to write something on the inputs and then click the button.

Comment: I've just written this as an example. I am still not in favour of using ``innerHTML``. What all I am saying is use ``appendChild`` and ``removeChild`` for add and remove functionality. The way it is mentioned by @Ray Soy

Comment: But the problem he has is that the value is lost, and with your answer the value is still lost, so you don't fixed anything. You just have rewritten the bug he is trying to solve xD